# Catching non-specific signals in C

Tags: c, unix, signals

I've read alot on here about catching signals in C. But all code examples I've seen are watching for specific signals. Like `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`.

Say that I have a program in which I want to check for signals. And I use this function in my `main` function: `signal(SIGINT, sighandler);` Where `sighandler` is my own defined function that looks something like this:

```
void sighandler(int signo)
{
    printf("\n Recieved signal %d", signo);
    signal(SIGINT, sighandler);
}
```

But If I want to check for more signals do I have to add more checks in my `main` function function like:

```
...
signal(SIGINT, sighandler);
signal(SIGTERM, sighandler);
signal(SIGILL, sighandler);
...
```

Or can I use like a wildcard(?) to catch multiple exceptions like say: `signal(SIGALL, sighandler);`. And then check in my function what has been sent?

```
void sighandler(int signo)
{
    printf("\n Recieved signal %d", signo);
    signal(signo, sighandler);
}
```

I hope my question is understandable and that I am not missing something very very obvious.

Comment: What is the objection to listing each signal you're catching in `main`?

Comment: @ChrisTurner If you want to catch **all** signals in a portable way, how can the list be made?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I can't think of a **portable** way to catch all signals, but since most signals aren't going to be relevant, I was asking why it's not possible to just list the ones they'll expect to get

Comment: @ChrisTurner `sigfillset()` or `NSIG`?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès if you've got an answer for the OP, maybe you should write one :)

Comment: Provided link in first comment is the one